# Geohashes - Why is interleaving index values necessary?

Tags: algorithm, geohashing

I have had a look at [this post](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves) about geohashes. According to the author, the final step in calculating the hash is interleaving the x and y index values. But is this really necessary? Is there a proper reason not to just concatenate these values, as long as the hash table is built according to that altered indexing rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)

> Geohashes offer properties like arbitrary precision and the
>   possibility of gradually removing characters from the end of the code
>   to reduce its size (and gradually lose precision).

If you simply concatenated x and y coordinates, then users would have to take a lot more care when trying to reduce precision by being careful to remove exactly the right number of characters from both the x and y coordinate.

Comment: Yes, you're right - didn't think of that, since for the geohash I'm building it is not necessary to reduce precision. - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related (and more important) reason than arbitrary precision: Geohashes with a common prefix are close to one another. The longer the common prefix, the closer they are.

```
54.321 -2.345 has geohash gcwm48u6
54.322 -2.346 has geohash gcwm4958
```

(See http://geohash.org to try this)

This feature enables fast lookup of nearby points (though there are some [complications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash#Limitations)), and only works because we interleave the two dimensions to get a sort of approximate 2D proximity metric.

As the wikipedia entry goes on to [explain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash#Uses):

> When used in a database, the structure of geohashed data has two
>   advantages. First, data indexed by geohash will have all points for a
>   given rectangular area in contiguous slices (the number of slices
>   depends on the precision required and the presence of geohash "fault
>   lines"). This is especially useful in database systems where queries
>   on a single index are much easier or faster than multiple-index
>   queries. Second, this index structure can be used for a
>   quick-and-dirty proximity search - the closest points are often among
>   the closest geohashes.

Note that the converse is not always true - if two points happen to lie on either side of a subdivision (e.g. either side of the equator) then they may be extremely close but have no common prefix. Hence the complications I mentioned earlier.